# Batch script to perform a set of commands based on specific field value in file

Tags: batch-file

I have a file that looks like this:

```
HDR,abc,UK,2.44
DTL,any,thing,written,here
HDR,lfk,US,43.11
DTL,once,again,anything,written
DTL,there,may,be,moreDTL
```

I need a batch script that can will search each HDR line and if a UK is found in the 3rd field, I need the HDR and the corresponding DTL segments to a file.  So in the example above, the first HDR and DTL will output to one location and the next HDR,DTL,DTL will output to another location.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This is not a free programming service. Have you made any attempt at doing this yourself?

Comment: Appreciate your comment Blorgbeard.  Yes, I have made many attempts and came up with something similar to mordecai's code but didn't want to make my posting convoluted. Just wanted to be direct. I am able to locate the 3rd field. I am having troubles outputting the entire segment and all it's fields, if field3=UK. If I do get that entire HDR segment written out, how do I write out the related DTL segments?

Comment: If you've got code, you should post the relevant part of it in the question, and explain exactly what you're having trouble with, and what form this trouble takes. As your question stands (your comment notwithstanding) it's a request for someone to implement it for you. Your post should indeed not be convoluted, but it should contain *some* details. @mordecai just wasted their time writing code that you already apparently have; that would have been avoided if you'd been more specific in your original post.

Answer (score 0):

Something small to get you going ....

@echo off

For /f "tokens=3,* delims=," %%a in (yourfile) do (

If "%%a"=="UK" (

Commands to execute If condition is true

) else (

Commands to execute if condition is false

)

)

Comment: I tried this before as well.  I tried to output the %%a,%%b,%%c and so forth to output the entire line.  But I still miss fields 1 & 2 and I cannot capture the DTL segments that are associated with that one HDR record.  And thank you for taking the time provide a starting point for me.

Comment: Note that the * (%%b) means every thing in the file every token the code is just using %%a as the third token to check if UK exists in 3rd token of every possible line so if you wish to output everything just use %%b which is *